# What's the $\int_0^T (T - s) dW_s$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $W_{t}$ be a Wiener process on a standard filtered probability space $(\Omega ,{\mathcal {F}},{\mathcal {F}}_{t},P)$ and let ${\mathcal {G}}_{t}$ be the augmented filtration generated by $B$. If $X$ is a square integrable random variable measurable with respect to ${\mathcal {G}}_{\infty }$, then there exists a predictable process $\Theta$ which is adapted with respect to ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {G}}_{t}}$, such that

$$X = EX + \int_0^T\Theta_s dW_s$$

where $W$ is a Wiener process

I want to prove that Ito representation of $X = \int_0^T W(s) ds$ is in form for $\Theta_s = (T-s)$.

**My work so far**

Let's calculate the integral $$\int_0^T (T-s)dW_s = \int_0^T TdW_s - \int_0^TsdW_s = T\int_0^TdW_s - \int_0^TsdW_s=$$
$$= TW_T - \int_0^TsdW_s$$

And now I have two problems:

$(1)$ Why $EX = E[\int_0^T W(s)ds] = 0 $ ?

$(2)$ I'm not exactly sure how to calculate this integral $\int_0^TsdW_s$. I read that partial integration should be used but I don't see how.

Could you please give me a hand in justifying $(1)$ and $(2)$  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for (1) it's only Fubini nothing more (as $E[W_s]=0$), for the (2) you have by stochastic integration by part (look for example [Theorem 3](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/01/18/quadratic-variations-and-integration-by-parts/)) that :

$$TW_T-0.W_0=\int_0^TsdW_s+\int_0^TW_sds+\int_0^Td\langle s,W_s\rangle=\int_0^TsdW_s+\int_0^TW_sds+0$$

So $\int_0^T (T-s)dWs =\int_0^TW_sds$

QED

Comment: Could you please expand on fact how Fubini theorem gives you $(1)$ ?

Comment: Ohh I get it! You have $E[\int..] = \int E[..] = 0$!

Comment: Yes that's it !!